# Setting Datepicker minDate after current datetime adds a text that show today on the top of DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker

If datepicker's min date is before current datetime DatepickerDialog view is normal. (First screenshot)

```
Calendar startDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, null, startDateCalendar
        .get(Calendar.YEAR), startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
datePicker.setMinDate(max.getTimeInMillis() - 100);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

If datepicker's min date is AFTER current datetime DatepickerDialog view adds a textview on top of the view that shows today. (Second screenshot)

```
Calendar startDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, null, startDateCalendar
        .get(Calendar.YEAR), startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        startDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
datePicker.setMinDate(max.getTimeInMillis() + 100);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 100);
datePickerDialog.setTitle(null);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Fast explain:

- setMinDate sets dialog title, we need to unset that
- use of `System.currentTimeMillis()` is more efficient than calling more complex `Calendar.getInstance()`